# OSMNX geometries_from_bbox tag for a single way

Tags: python, osmnx

Probably simpler than I think: I have a function that pulls geometries_from_bbox with tags like

`'building':True`

That works fine, but this

`'way':12345`

doesn't seem to work. How can I pull a single way by id via geometries_from_bbox?

Answer (score 1):

OSMnx's `geometries` module only queries by tag/value: [docs](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#module-osmnx.geometries).

Instead, use OSMnx's `geocode` module to retrieve an object by place name **or by OSM ID**:

```py
import osmnx as ox
ox.geocode_to_gdf(query="W398261765", by_osmid=True)
```

Comment: Also note that the `geometries` module was renamed the `features` module in OSMnx 1.5.0.